# Consultar un campo de texto por varias palabras sin importar el orden de las mismas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Me gustaría saber la forma de hacer que mi buscador encuentre resultados sin importar el orden en el que lo escribes.

Ejemplo
Si busco "coche color rojo" me encuentra todos los resultados que contengan "coche color rojo"
Pero si busco "coche rojo" o " rojo coche" no encuentra nada.

Como podría hacer para que me arroje resultados buscando sin orden?

Este es el codigo

```
$q=$_POST["q"];


$sql="SELECT * FROM items WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$q."%'";
$res = $link->query($sql);

if(!$res || mysqli_num_rows($res) == 0){

echo '<b>No hay Resultados</b>';

}else{

echo '<b>Resultados:</b><br />';

while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){?>

´´´
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba generando el SQL así:

```
<?php

$busqueda='coche color rojo';

$sql="SELECT * FROM items WHERE 1";
foreach(explode(' ',$busqueda) as $termino)
    $sql.=" AND nombre LIKE '%".$termino."%'";

echo $sql;
```

Este código PHP te generará un SQL tal que así:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE 1 
  AND nombre LIKE '%coche%'
  AND nombre LIKE '%color%'
  AND nombre LIKE '%rojo%';
```

Con el que se localizarán aquellos registros cuyo campo `nombre` contenga todos los términos sin importar el orden.

Comment: Gracias! lo consegui. GRANDE!!

Answer (score 0):

Solución

```
$q=$_POST["q"];


$sql="SELECT * FROM items WHERE 1";
foreach(explode(' ',$busqueda) as $termino)
    $sql.=" AND nombre LIKE '%".$termino."%'";´

$res = $link->query($sql);

if(!$res || mysqli_num_rows($res) == 0){

echo '<b>No hay Resultados</b>';

}else{

echo '<b>Resultados:</b><br />';

while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){?>
´´
```

Comment: ¿Entonces cuál es la respuesta, la tuya o la de David?

Comment: Por favor, no agregues una respuesta que sea la solucion dada mas tu codigo, ya que no aporta nada mas a tu pregunta.. se agradece, pero no es necesario

Answer (score 0):

Se que es algo viejo, pero sé que alguien más puede necesitarlo, tenía este problema y hace tiempo vi que se podía usar funciones `REGEXP` en SQL, luego perdí el articulo y me volví a ver en la necesidad de implantar algo así y lo volví a encontrar.

```
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE `columna` REGEXP 'texto1|texto2|texto3';
```

Incluso si hay palabras que no coinciden, igual retornará los resultados más cercanos.
Ejemplo: si se busca "MacBook air amarilla 2015 Apple".

```
SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `nombre` REGEXP 'macbook|air|amarilla|2015|apple';
```

La persona verá todos los MacBook air, aunque no sea amarilla, dando más resultados en una tienda en línea, por ejemplo, donde la meta es vender y mostrarles alternativas a los clientes, aunque no sea lo que buscara.

Pueden poner el parámetro `REGEXP` como deseen, más información aquí: https://www.scaler.com/topics/regex-in-sql/

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]. Estaría excelente que hagas un ejemplo dinámico, tal como muestra la respuesta aceptada. Por cierto, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, así de paso obtienes tu primera [medalla](/help/badges).